# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using PHP, SQL SERVER and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

I have a select that depends on another select, I want to realize it using (PHP, SQL SERVER, JQUERY, AJAX) but I still have this error

> ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at Object. (GenerateQuery.js:29)
>           at fire (jquery-3.3.1_2.js:3268)
>           at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1_2.js:3398)
>           at done (jquery-3.3.1_2.js:9305)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.3.1_2.js:9548)

here is my code

JQUERy :

```
$('#srces').change(function(){

    var tid=$('#srces').val();

    srcee.attr("disabled", true);
        tab.removeAttr('disabled');
    $.ajax({
      url:'data.php',
      method:"POST",
      data: 'tid6='+tid

    }).done(function(colonn){

      colonn=JSON.parse(colonn);

      $('#tables').empty();
      $('#tables').append('<option selected disabled="disabled">Choisir...</option>');
      colonn.forEach(function(result){
        $('#tables').append('<option value="'+result.nomReal+'">'+result.NomTable+'</option>');
      });
    });
});
```

data.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['tid6'])){

        $serverName = "localhost"; //serverName\instanceName
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Automatisation", "UID"=>"Dev", "PWD"=>"root");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM Table";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

        $result = array();
        do {
            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
               $result[] = $row;

            }
        } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));


        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: Something is wrong in the JSON you are receiving from the server. At a guess it is sending html because the JSON error mentions < as the first character. Try to see or log the JSON coming from the server side.